# Django sending email with template

Tags: django, image, email, templates

I want to send email using Django. In the mail body , I want to send Bootstrap "Card" which contain "Image" and HTML content.

Sending mail is successful. But, It is not showing the image in the received mail. Also, It is not in the Bootstrap "Card" format.

Please some one help me.

### views.py

```
emailSubject = "Mail from XYZ.COM"
emailOfSender = EMAIL_HOST_USER
emailOfRecipient = viewed_bog.profile.user.email

html_content = render_to_string('receipt_email.html', {'item': viewed_bog, }, request=request)

try:        
    emailMessage = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject=emailSubject, body=html_content,      
                   from_email=emailOfSender,                                           
                   to=[emailOfRecipient, ], reply_to=[emailOfSender, ])
    emailMessage.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
    emailMessage.send(fail_silently=False)

except SMTPException as e:
    print('There was an error sending an email: ', e)
```

### receipt_email.html

This is the HTML template containing Bootstrap 4 "Card" using Django-templating language. With in the Card I am having Image.

Now, I am able to send mail successfully. But Image is not showing in the received mail. and also, mail body is not in the "Card" format.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you are loading the css from a bootstrap.css file and as most mail providers block loading css and js files for security reasons you should use inline styling in the template that you want to send.
Eventually this an online tool that i use when i want to compile regular css to inline css.
[css inline tool](https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/)

Comment: Wallid, I have tried with the "css inline tool" mentioned above. It is not solving the problem.

Comment: when receiving the email does it happen to have some error logs on the browser console ?

Comment: Yes Mr wallid, errors are coming like this 1)Content Security Policy: Ignoring “'unsafe-inline'” within script-src: ‘strict-dynamic’ specified 2) Content Security Policy: Ignoring “https:” within script-src: ‘strict-dynamic’ specified. In "receipt_email.html" file, I am using basic Bootstrap "card" and for displaying image as per django templating language, {% if item.photo %} {{ item.photo.url }} {% endif %}. In the received mail, It is not showing image and also it is not in bootstrap "card" format.